# Equivalence between "windowed Fourier transform" and STFT as convolutions/filtering

Tags: dft, convolution, stft, time-frequency

I've heard, that "windowed Fourier transform" is but one perspective on STFT, and that STFT is fundamentally convolutions of windowed complex sinusoids with the input, i.e. bandpass filtering. Yet the standard implementation and perspective on STFT is, take a segment of input `x_seg = x[start:end]`, window it `x_seg * window`, and take its FFT (DFT).

Is that really equivalent to `conv(x, window * cisoid)`? How so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer isn't fully developed (but is correct), I may update in the future.

Indeed, STFT is strided convolutions, and there's many practical caveats, discussed in this answer.

### Standard vs improved STFT

Standard:

$$
\text{STFT}_x(\tau, \omega) = 
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) w(t - \tau) e^{-j\omega t} dt
$$

It's what most libraries (including MATLAB, `scipy`, `librosa`) implement. In short, its complex-valued result is [suboptimal](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1279), or even flawed - it lacks some important properties of time-frequency transforms, e.g. [one-integral inverse](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76239/50076) and zero phase (even if window is zero phase), making it ill-suited for many kinds of operations on complex values - though the modulus (spectrogram) is unaffected.

The better variant, implemented in [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy), writes

$$
\text{STFT}_x^\text{mod}(\tau, \omega) = 
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) w(t - \tau) e^{-j\omega (t - \tau)} dt
$$

I'm unsure whether MATLAB is really implementing "standard"; see "Demos" below.

---

### STFT as convolutions

The simplicity of STFT is obfuscated in the "windowed Fourier" implementation. Now let's visualize:

[image]

Usually, we take DFT (FFT) or DTFT of this and call this "the frequency response" and do lobe analysis. But **that's wrong**! (Before I get pitchforked, see "caveats" below.) The true operators of STFT are convolutions, hence the true frequency response is that of its filters padded to the convolution length. Below is that, on the $\texttt{STFT}^{\texttt{mod}}$ variant:

[image]

That's the real part, with imaginary zero: zero-phase, as is ideal. For complex input, the filters would also completely tile the negative frequencies. Note, despite center frequencies being positive-only, there's still leaks into negatives - hence loss of analyticity. Brief detour:

#### Convolution <=> Windowed Fourier equivalence

"Windowed Fourier transform" takes DFT of a windowed segment of `x`. Output of DFT at e.g. index 3, is the inner product of a complex sinusoid at DFT frequency 3, with input to DFT, which here is the windowed segment. I.e., it's `sum(x_seg * window * cisoid(f=3))`, and that's assigned to `STFT[3, seg_idx]`. More concretely,

- Let `y = fft(x)`, and `N=len(x)`. `y[3]` is equal to `sum(x * np.exp(-1j * 2*np.pi * 3 * np.arange(N) / N))` - or, `sum(x * cisoid(f=3))`.
- Hence, `fft(x * window)` just replaces `x` with `x * window` above: `sum(x * window * cisoid(f=3))`

This is repeated for all hops and `f` to produce the full STFT. Below are `window * cisoid(f)` for two `f`:

[image]

Above is exactly describing *convolution* of `x` with `window * cisoid(f)`, where `len(x_seg) < len(x)` is permitted since `window` is time-limited. Yet, for reasons, it's a flawed implementation of said convolution - the modulus is correct, but phase messy; separate topic. We assume $\texttt{STFT}^{\texttt{mod}}$ throughout.

#### STFT filterbank (cont'd)

`out[4, :]` is hence computed by convolving with `filter4 = window * cisoid(f=4)`. Multiplication in time is convolution in frequency - hence, the frequency response of `filter4` is the frequency response of `window` convolved with frequency response of `cisoid(f=4)` - latter is just a unit impulse, and the result is *shifting* the frequency response of `window` to `f=4`. Repeat for all `f`, and we get the `fbank_f0` plot.

Now, let's check `n_fft < N`:

[image]

With all said so far, it makes sense that if `N / n_fft` is integer, then `fbank_f1` is a subset of `fbank_f0`; you'll find in code, `np.allclose(fbank_f1, fbank_f0[::4]) == True`.

Now, for `N / n_fft` that's a fraction, superimposed with above filterbank (orange):

[image]

No longer a subset, but some frequencies may still coincide.

#### Demos

Let $x(t)$ be sum of pure sines of frequencies $4, 20, 40, 60$, with $N=128$ samples. We have:

[image]

[image]

"Standard" introduces behavioral dependence on `n_fft` while "improved" resamples at higher resolution as intended; "standard" indicates modulations along frequency for a pure tone, which is nonsense. These have reaching implications which amount to largely invalidating the 2D time-frequency structure of the complex-valued STFT.

MATLAB's `stft`, from my limited experimentation, has yet additional distortions (ignore edge effects):

[image]

This shouldn't be possible in either variant, "standard" or "improved", I've no clue where it's coming from. Likely, it's still "standard", but with extra steps that don't fit the standard's mathematical formulation - I welcome others' input here. (Note, here it looks closer to "improved", but other examples I've tried rule it out.)

```matlab
t = 0:1/128:(1 - 1/128);
x = cos(2*pi*30*t);
xp = cat(2, zeros(1, 10), x, zeros(1, 9));
Sxx = real(stft(xp, Window=hamming(20), OverlapLength=19, FFTLength=128));

imagesc(Sxx(1:65, :)); figure
plot(Sxx(30, 45:70)); hold on; plot(Sxx(32, 45:70)); plot(Sxx(34, 45:70));
```

#### Caveats / observations

1. Above when I say convolution, I actually mean cross-correlation.
2. `n_fft=N` corresponds to (actually) convolution of `fft(window)` with `fft(x)` for the overall frequency response of STFT
3. Even if original `window` is zero-phase, it may not be so in the true response. In fact, in majority of cases, it's not - though it's often close. Zero-phase requires [DFT-symmetry](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Window_function#/DFT-symmetry) - and, for example, zero-padding kills that for even-length DFT-symmetric windows with no zeros in `window`. But zero-padding isn't causing the problem, only exposing it.
4. "But **that's wrong!**" - it's correct *columnwise*. But almost any time we speak of filtering, we speak of `conv(x, filter)`, and `fft(window)` doesn't reflect that. More importantly, zero-padding in one domain is interpolation in another - meaning, the magnitude response of `fft(window)` remains accurate; it's phase that most likely isn't.
5. `hop_size = 4` is just `hop_size = 1` with convolution stride `4`, or equivalently, subsampling `STFT(x, hop_size=1)` by a factor of `4`, like so: `Sx4 = Sx1[:, ::4]`. The effects on frequency are understood via [subsampling in time <=> folding in frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74734/50076).
6. STFT pads and unpads, and [unpadding is aliasing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/83082/50076) - in this case exact frequency representation is (likely) impossible, but in most cases it's very close.
7. `scipy`'s `sym=False` for odd lengths is [incorrect](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/18033)

### CWT animation

[image]

1. Slide wavelet `psi_i` by some time shift `tau`
2. Compute similarity (inner product, `sum(x * psi)`)
3. Repeat for all `tau` and `psi_i`

### STFT animation

It's exactly "CWT animation", where `psi_i = fft(window * cisoid_i)` (`i` is index of a given frequency, and `window` is full length), except

1. Filter bandwidth is constant
2. Filters are spaced uniformly (linearly distributed)

There's also zero-mean enforcement in CWT, but that's negligible for our purposes.

### What's in code

I provide a limited row-wise implementation of STFT (mod) for exploration purposes, that also returns the exact filterbank used to compute STFT. Main caveats:

1. The filterbanks aren't actually zero-phase, though it's very close - per technicalities, I've not had time to account for it, though you could. Easiest workaround is `scipy.signal.windows` with input length `N`.
2. There's no padding, but it's equivalently `'wrap'` (periodic) padding. This bypasses the unpadding caveat and represents the filters perfectly. It can also be worked around by passing padded `x` as input, and unpadding the output.

### How to translate between standard and "mod" implems?

It's a simple conversion - code at [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/ssqueezepy/_stft.py), discussion [here](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1279#issuecomment-774792464) (also see comments above the one linked).

### Code

Available at [Github](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/StackExchangeAnswers/tree/main/SignalProcessing/Q86937%20-%20STFT%20-%20Equivalence%20of%20Windowed%20Fourier%20and%20Convolutions).

Comment: Great explanation of two different interpretations of the STFT (sliding windowed transform vs complex filterbank). I especially appreciate the often-missed fact that the *hop size* from the sliding window view can be mapped to a *downsampling* factor in the complex filterbank view. And thank you for the great CWT animation!

Comment: @Jdip Well it's good to see someone other than I acknowledge this, I've never seen it elsewhere and keep (re)inventing stuff. Only saw it in a synchrosqueezing paper, and all they say is, "it's convenient for our purposes"... like, ok?? More like "absolutely necessary and for good reasons".

Comment: Hay, [I'm in agreement with you about the "Improved STFT"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45625/is-windowed-fourier-transform-a-synonym-for-stft/45631#45631).